# Convert windows media video stream to mp3 audio?

Tags: conversion, mp3, streaming, media, mencoder

I'd like to take a windows media video stream and convert it to mp3 audio. Using mencoder I can convert from windows media video to avi but not directly from windows media to mp3. The following is the command I use to convert to avi, but I'd like to avoid having to do two conversions and converting the avi file to mp3.
`mencoder mms://wmslive.media.hinet.net/Weblive_Bloomberg_600 -ovc lavc -oac mp3lame -o output.avi`
Note if there are tools that can do this I will use them, I have access to both Linux and Windows.

Comment: can someone try this: mplayer -dumpaudio mms://whatever -dumpfile nodame_theme.mp3  I have a lame ISP and I can't hit many non-standard ports in a lot of places(git and svn are blocked for europe and china too)

Answer (score 2):

I think your best bet is to use `mencoder` to convert to AVI, then use a tool like `ffmpeg` or `tcextract` (from the `transcode` package` to extract the MP3:

```
$ ffmpeg -i in.avi -acodec copy out.mp3

$ tcextract -i foo.avi -x mp3 > out.mp3
```

Using `tcextract` will do **no re-encoding at all** and is very fast.  `ffmpeg` isn't supposed to be doing any reprocessing but it's much slower.  (Tested on a ~22min AVI file.)

Sadly, it doesn't seem "possible" to do this in one step with `mencoder`.  I tried a couple of different things:

- `mencoder mms://wmslive.media.hinet.net/Weblive_Bloomberg_600 -novideo -oac mp3lame -o out.mp3`

  This reports `Video stream is mandatory!`.  No good.
- `mencoder mms://wmslive.media.hinet.net/Weblive_Bloomberg_600 -vc null -oac mp3lame -o out.mp3`

  This complains about no `-ovc` option, but since there's no `-ovc null` option, that won't do either.

Here's the stream data from `mplayer -identify`:

```
ASF file format detected.
ID_AUDIO_ID=1
[asfheader] Audio stream found, -aid 1
ID_VIDEO_ID=2
[asfheader] Video stream found, -vid 2
VIDEO:  [WMV3]  512x384  24bpp  1000.000 fps  552.0 kbps (67.4 kbyte/s)
Clip info:
 name:
ID_CLIP_INFO_NAME0=name
ID_CLIP_INFO_VALUE0=
 author:
ID_CLIP_INFO_NAME1=author
ID_CLIP_INFO_VALUE1=
 copyright:
ID_CLIP_INFO_NAME2=copyright
ID_CLIP_INFO_VALUE2=
 comments:
ID_CLIP_INFO_NAME3=comments
ID_CLIP_INFO_VALUE3=
ID_CLIP_INFO_N=4
ID_FILENAME=mms://wmslive.media.hinet.net/Weblive_Bloomberg_600
ID_DEMUXER=asf
ID_VIDEO_FORMAT=WMV3
ID_VIDEO_BITRATE=552000
ID_VIDEO_WIDTH=512
ID_VIDEO_HEIGHT=384
ID_VIDEO_FPS=1000.000
ID_VIDEO_ASPECT=0.0000
ID_AUDIO_FORMAT=353
ID_AUDIO_BITRATE=0
ID_AUDIO_RATE=0
ID_AUDIO_NCH=0
ID_LENGTH=2133437386.00
ID_SEEKABLE=0
```

Comment: This is basically what I did. I have a cron job set up to use mencoder to record a stream as an avi file for an hour, then transcode the avi to mp3 using ffmpeg, then speed the mp3 up with sox.

Comment: You can use ffmpeg without converting to AVI first.

Answer (score 2):

Use free tool, for example Any Audio Converter:

http://www.any-audio-converter.com/

Answer (score 1):

Try VLC. Works for practically anything.
http://videolan.org

Answer (score 1):

Not very intuitive, but this seems to do it:

```
mencoder -of rawaudio -ovc copy -oac mp3lame
```

Answer (score 0):

For windows, any of the free video to audio converting tools like

**effectmatrix.com/total-video-converter** OR 
  **jetaudio.com**

Jet Audio is a full-fledged media player as well as converter tool
(sorry for typing links like this, but superuser is not allowing me to post more than two links, some sort of spam-protection error popping in **sigh**)

For linux, the in-built [ff-mpeg](http://ffmpeg.org/) will do the job (See documentation of ff-mpeg for the correct syntax on how to do the job)

Answer (score 0):

`ffmpeg -i nameoffile.wmv nameoffile.mp3`

Comment: I must admit to to being curious why my correct answer was downvoted.

Comment: I didn't do it, but probably because this was already answered by quack quixote. Best to delete your answer, to avoid more such.

Comment: Quack's answer is much more complex than mine.  I'm not being defensive so much as puzzled.

Comment: Testing this on two different WMV's, it only gives `unsupported codec`. Quack's answer however, does convert. Playing the file though does not: `could not determine type of stream`

Comment: There are at least a dozen FFMPEG compilations for Windows. Sounds like you found one that doesn't support the Windows Media codecs.

Answer (score 0):

From [How to capture, save, record or download streaming audio for free](http://www.online-tech-tips.com/computer-tips/how-to-capture-save-record-or-download-streaming-audio-for-free/) (Windows) :

> One surefire way of recording
>   streaming audio from any web site  is
>   to simply capture it via the sound
>   card on your computer.
>
> If you don’t mind having another
>   toolbar installed in your browser
>   window, [FreeCorder](http://freecorder.com/freecorder3/) is a very
>   convenient program to use if you’re
>   going to be recording music that’s
>   mostly played via the web, such as
>   Internet radio, etc. Also, it has many
>   other features that make it quite
>   useful, such as the ability to extract
>   audio from videos and record from your
>   PC’s microphone or line-in port.
>
> If you don’t like the idea of
>   cluttering up your browser toolbar,
>   you can use a standalone program
>   called [MP3MyMP3 Recorder](http://www.mp3mymp3.com/mp3_my_mp3_recorder.html), which
>   is also free. Like FreeCorder, this
>   program also records whatever is being
>   played by your computer’s speakers.
>   However, unlike FreeCorder, this
>   program requires that your sound NOT
>   be muted.