# Convert movie audio from ac3 to mp3 ? (no video conv.)

Tags: audio, conversion, mp3, video-conversion, ac3

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Convert mp4 to mp3](https://superuser.com/questions/76951/convert-mp4-to-mp3)

Hello everybody,

Could you please suggest me a quick way to convert just the audio of movies from AC3 to MP3 ?
I would like to get a new Avi with the same video, but different audio (mp3).
OS: windows 7.

(I do not need to convert video, just audio)

thank you !

Comment: possible duplicate of [Convert mp4 to mp3](http://superuser.com/questions/76951/convert-mp4-to-mp3) and/or [Convert windows media video stream to mp3 audio?](http://superuser.com/questions/64363/convert-windows-media-video-stream-to-mp3-audio)

Answer (score 3):

You can do it with ffmpeg. Try a command line like this:

```
ffmpeg -i <input_filename> -f <container> -vcodec copy -acodec libmp3lame -ar 44100 -ab 128k -ac 2 <output_filename>
```

Replace the <> stuff with whatever filenames and containers you are using. Do note that this will downmix surround to 2 channel audio.

Comment: Could downmixing be avoided by removing `-ac 2`?

Comment: @grawity mp3 doesn't support more than 2 channels

Comment: any graphical software please :) ??